# Retrieve wpa_supplicant configuration generated by NetworkManager

Tags: linux, debian, networkmanager, wpa, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to debug a NetworkManager-powered wireless connection. It works when I feed `wpa_supplicant` with a custom `wpa_supplicant.conf` file written by me, but when I configure NetworkManager with the same parameters it does not work. I would like to know the exact parameters that NetworkManager is feeding to wpa_supplicant in order to compare with my custom configuration.

I can connect to `wpa_supplicant` using `wpa_cli` and I can retrieve each single parameter. But I would like to have a way to dump the whole configuration at once, or at least a way to have a list of *all* the parameters that I can fetch.

My system is running Debian sid with up-to-date packages.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar problem: a connection not working with manual `wpa_supplicant.conf`, but with `NetworkManager` and with `wpa_cli` both working, so this helped me to determine that `NetworkManager` is not the way to go. `wpa_cli` > `save_config` (with `wpa_supplicant.conf:update_config=1` finally worked for me.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't "dump" the set of parameters with wpa_cli. But have you taken a look at the files in the folder `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`? Could prove handy, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but that is not really what I want. I do not want the NM configuration, but the wpa_supplicant configuration generated by NM (because I think that this generation process is buggy in my case). Something of it appear in the syslog, but I wonder whether there is a way to collect it all together.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkManager sends it to wpa_supplicant over D-bus.

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2013-June/msg00126.html

https://askubuntu.com/questions/75872/where-are-the-networkmanager-logs

It is in the D-bus logs. For me it was in /var/log/syslog but I think it varies depending on the distro. It shows  some lines like

```
Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
...
```